# How to fix Repeated Storing Data to DB table using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am struggling to prevent the data from repeating in my db table, even chat gpt keeps on repeating the solution.

here is the code from visual studio

```
var premArrearsGet = await _autoLISContext.PremArrears.Where(e => e.REG_NUMBER == REG_NUMBER_PL).ToListAsync();

            _ = premArrearsGet;

            foreach (var premArrearsItem in premArrearsGet)
            {
                var newEntity = new prem_arrears_pl
                {
                    REG_NUMBER = premArrearsItem.REG_NUMBER,
                    AUTO_NUMBER = premArrearsItem.AUTO_NUMBER,
                    
                };

                _context.PremArrearsPL.Add(newEntity);
            }
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

in this code, I added a variable just to check the count using breakpoint. The count is correct, it shows 3 counts (0 - 2) but the data stored in the table is the data from count 0 and just keep on repeating
[image]

[image]

please help me with this, Thanks

Comment: the data from auto_number should be 875, 876, 877

Comment: Are you sure the source data is unique? And if you want an auto generated number why not use an `Identity` column?

Comment: the reg number is not unique, only the auto number is unique and auto identity.

Comment: So the next debug step is check the values of `REG_NUMBER = premArrearsItem.REG_NUMBER` and `AUTO_NUMBER = premArrearsItem.AUTO_NUMBER` and confirm whther they are the same or different in each iteration.

Comment: If they are all the same number I highly doubt that auto_number is an "auto identity", SQL does not create duplicates.

Comment: Try to use SSMS to view the table designer, whether the AUTO_NUMBER column is Identity or not? If it is not an Identity column, the value will not auto increment. Refer to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqnTV.png), in this case, you need to add the increment manually. Or you can modify the table designer to change the AUTO_NUMBER column to Identity.